# Finding an orthonormal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V=M_2(\mathbb{R})$ with $\left\langle A,B\right\rangle:=\text{tr}\left(AB^*\right)$ and $A=\left(\begin{array}{cc} 4 & 1 \\ -3 & 3 \end{array}\right)$ find $B\in M_2(\mathbb{R})$ such that $B$ will be orthonormal with respect to the inner product $\left\langle A,B\right\rangle:=\text{tr}\left(AB^*\right)$
What I have thought about is that the matrix $B$ have to fulfill:

a.  $$\left(\begin{array}{cc} 4 & 1 \\ -3 & 3 \end{array}\right)\cdot \left(\begin{array}{cc} x_1 & x_2 \\ x_3 & x_4 \end{array}\right)=0$$
b.$$x_1\cdot \bar{x_1}+x_4\cdot \bar{x_4}=1$$

But I get to more equations than veriables

Comment: There is something wrong. If you solve the first matrix equation for $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$ you'll easily notice that $x_1 = x_2 = x_3 = x_4 = 0$.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly? you should find $B$ so that ${\rm tr} A B^*=0$ and ${\rm tr} B B^*=1$. This leads to two different equations than yours. (and there are many solutions)

Comment: The field is $\mathbf{R}$, so your adjoint matrix is the transpose. That eliminates the conjugate part. If you go through the normal property, you will find that your matrix $B$ is symmetric. That eliminates 2 more variables.

Comment: @H.H.Rugh you are right I was mistaken about part 1

Comment: @H.H.Rugh so in a. I get $4x_1+x_2-3x_3+3x_4=0$?

Comment: Yes, you have now got a complete solution below. But the scalar product given is really just like a usual scalar product between vectors with 4 components. (and seems that it is real in your case?)

Comment: I changed the content of the body to match your title. Your question is completely different from the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$B=\left(\begin{matrix} x_1 & x_2 \\ x_3 & x_4 \end{matrix}\right)$ orthonormal mean that :

1) $\langle A, B\rangle =tr(AB^*)=0$

2) $\langle B, B\rangle =tr(BB^*)=1$

so $2)$ implies that 
\begin{eqnarray}
1&=& tr(BB^*)\\
&=& tr\left[\left(\begin{matrix} x_1 & x_2 \\ x_3 & x_4 \end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix} \bar x_1 & \bar x_3 \\ \bar x_2 & \bar x_4 \end{matrix}\right) \right]\\
&=& tr\left[\left(\begin{matrix} |x_1|^2+|x_2|^2 & \alpha  \\ \beta & |x_3|^2+|x_4|^2 \end{matrix}\right) \right]\\
&=& |x_1|^2+|x_2|^2+|x_3|^2+|x_4|^2
\end{eqnarray}
and $1)$ mean that :
\begin{eqnarray}
0&=& tr(AB^*)\\
&=& tr\left[\left(\begin{matrix} 4 & 1 \\ -3 & 3 \end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix} \bar x_1 & \bar x_3 \\ \bar x_2 & \bar x_4 \end{matrix}\right) \right]\\
&=& tr\left[\left(\begin{matrix} 4\bar x_1+\bar x_2 & \alpha'  \\ \beta' & 3(\bar x_4-\bar x_3) \end{matrix}\right) \right]\\
&=& 4\bar x_1+\bar x_2 +3(\bar x_4-\bar x_3)
\end{eqnarray}
so your final system is :
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
 |x_1|^2+|x_2|^2+|x_3|^2+|x_4|^2=1\\
4 x_1+ x_2 +3( x_4- x_3)=0
\end{array}
\right.
$$
so the set of solution of this equation is a manifold of dimension 3.

we can write it as :
$$
x_2=3(x_3-x_4)-4x_1 
$$
so the set of solution is :
$$
S=\left\{
 \frac{1}{\sqrt{|a|^2+| 3(c-d)-4a|^2+|c|^2+|d|^2}}\left(\begin{matrix} a & 3(c-d)-4a\\ c&d \end{matrix}\right) \textrm{ such that } a,b,c \in \mathbb{C}-\{0\}\right\}
$$

Comment: after the comments above this is the set of equations.
for the second equation I set $x_2=x_3=0$ and got $4x_1=-3x_4$ but it can not satsfity the first equation too

Comment: can you see now the explicit set of solution ?